# Extract and Modify cdata section of xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, cdata

I have the following xml

```
<parent>
    <child>abra</child>
    <child>kadabra</child>
    <child>alakazam</child>
    <![CDATA[ some data here ]]>
</parent>
```

I want to extract the cdata section, what I have done is - converted the data into string and extracted it with the following code

```
string toText = xmlDoc.OuterXml.Substring(xmlDoc.OuterXml.IndexOf("<![CDATA[") + "<![CDATA[".Length);
toText = toText.Remove(toText.IndexOf("]]>"));
```

where xmlDoc is XMLDocument which contails above xml

Is there any better way of doing this?

I googled a lot, but what I got is extraction of cdata section only if its the only child of its parent element.

Finally I want to modify cdata section and modify the current xml as

```
<parent>
    <child>abra</child>
    <child>kadabra</child>
    <child>alakazam</child>
    <![CDATA[ modified data here ]]>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given this *valid* XML sample :

```
<parent>
    <child>1</child>
    <child>2</child>
    <child>3</child>
    <![CDATA[ some data here ]]>
</parent>
```

Since the only text node that is direct child of `<parent>` is the cdata section you want to get, you can do this way to select the cdata section and modify it's content :

```
var cdata = (XmlCDataSection)xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/parent/text()");
cdata.InnerText = " modified data here ";
Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
```

Another possible approach is using [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to replace the older library, `XmlDocument` :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_your_xml");
var xcdata = doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XCData>().FirstOrDefault();
xcdata.Value = " modified data here ";
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

The output is as follow (formatted for readability) :

```
<parent>
    <child>1</child>
    <child>2</child>
    <child>3</child>
    <![CDATA[ modified data here ]]>
</parent>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot har07 . It worked. It helped my understanding a lot. :)